# How can I prune my SSISDB Tables on a busy SSIS environment while the system is running?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I recently had a need to clean up my SSISDB Database as the Table Row Counts and Sizes were growing so large that I was running out of drive space on my SQL Server.  After combing the web and getting some ideas from others who have battled this same issue, I came up with my own solution to handle pruning data from my SSISDB Database.

Here's my git link to my solution: https://github.com/martyscherr/SSISDB_Cleanup  I have included a README.md file explaining my solution.  My main reason I don't use the built-in data pruning options that Microsoft provides is that I needed to control the row counts when I was deleting data from the SSISDB tables.  Also I wanted to be some logging of the process and I used a TRY/CATCH exception block and explicit transactions to control the process.  If you get a chance, please take a look at my solution and send me any feedback.

As a disclaimer: This process is by no means 100% bug free, but I felt I made a decent effort to create a solution that would have minimal impact to my very busy SSIS environment but prune the SSISDB tables on a daily basis.

I choose to only keep 3 days of data based on the the main table in the SSISDB data structure:  SSISDB.internal.operations.  I prune data older than 3 days based on the created_time column of that table.  I have documented the Referential Integrity of the SSISDB tables as that played a factor in the performance of the pruning process.  When I analyzed the SSISDB Table structures I was reminded that the SSISDB has foreign key constraints on many of the tables and utilizes the ON DELETE CASCADE clause on the Foreign Key statement.

I found that if I didn't drop the Foreign Keys before I ran my pruning process it was not very efficient.  So I choose to drop the Foreign Keys during the process and create them again when the process completes.  I have SQL Scripts to validate that the Referential Integrity after the pruning process to confirm that Referential Integrity was maintained.   If you have time, please check out my solution and give me any feedback you may have.

Link to an article I used which was a great help in creating my solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/134523/how-do-i-clean-ssisdb-running-on-azure-sql-databas